# Setting variables based on the last element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array like this:

```
"spellsCount": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000000
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000001
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000002
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000003
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000005
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000009
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000011
    }
  ],
```

Now what I need to do is make a php loop or something that will go through that entire array and make variables with a value of 0;

Now the tricky bit is that not all `GlobalID`s show in that array. For example `26000010` is not showing.

I need it to make a variable like
`$spells26000000 = 0;`
for each item. INCLUDING ones that are in between but are missing. So there would also be a variable `$spells26000010 = 0;` if the above array was used.

Initally I had this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i+=1){// start at index 0 (1st value) and increment by 1
    if (isset($data['spellsCount'][$i])) {  // just in case there aren't actually 100
        // Use variable variables to create the $achievement variables you want
        $globalID = $data['spellsCount'][$i]['globalID'];
        ${"spells$globalID"} = $data['spellsCount'][$i]['value'];
    }
}
```

But then I realized that some values won't always show so I figured out I need to do it like this but I am not sure how to.

By the way! I am using `json_decode` like this `$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);`

Comment: Wait...so what are you trying to do? Dynamically create variables? What is happening instead when you try to do this?

Comment: @Zarathuztra my current code works but it doesn't fill in the gaps. For example you can see the globalID ending in 10 isn't in the array but it needs to be made a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(data(), true);
$spellsCounts = [];
// make the globalID the index of each respective element
foreach($data['spellsCount'] as $sc) {
    $spellsCounts[ $sc['globalID'] ] = $sc;
}
// sort the elements by ascending key (i.e. globalID)
ksort($data);

// run from first.globalID==min to end.globalID==max
$min = reset($spellsCounts)['globalID']; // Function array dereferencing has been added in php 5.4
$max = end($spellsCounts)['globalID'];
for($i=$min; $i<=$max; $i++) {
    // ....but this just doesn't sound right
    // it's just polluting the namespace
    ${'spells'.$i} = isset($spellsCounts[$i]) ? $spellsCounts[$i]['value'] : 'n/a';
}

// how about using the $spellsCount array
// and fill it up with the missing values ( in case you really need that) ?
for($i=$min; $i<=$max; $i++) {
    // ....but this just doesn't sound right
    if ( !isset($spellsCounts[$i]) ) {
        $spellsCounts[$i] = [
            'globalID' => $i,
            'value' => 'n/a'
        ];
    }
}
var_dump($spellsCounts);



function data() {
    return '{"spellsCount": [
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000000
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000001
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000002
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000003
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000005
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000009
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "globalID": 26000011
    }
  ]}';
}
```

Comment: btw: I think it's an XY-problem. This answer should technically answer your question but I really doubt it will efficiently solve your problem (i.e. _what_ you want to achieve, not _how_ ).

Comment: I'll test this out and see what it does and if it works.